# iPhone: Force UIButton to redraw itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, sleep, redraw

I got 5 `UIButtons` placed next to each other and what I wanna do is set image on first button, redraw it so it, wait for 1 second, then set some other image on second button, redraw second button and so on.
I tried to set image on button, then call function sleep(1) and so on but it just freezes application for 5 seconds and then redraws all 5 buttons at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) to delay the image changes.